# How do I define an XSLT test that test for duplicate XML element node values

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am a novice with XSLT and complex XPATH statements.  I've struggled to determine why the following XPATH test fails to find duplicate  values within an  node.

This is my XSLT test logic (the complete XSLT template= has been omitted for brevity):

```
<xsl:template match="/atom:feed/atom:entry" priority="4000" mode="M5">

    <!--ASSERT -->
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="count(/atom:feed/atom:entry[atom:id = current()/atom:id]) &gt; 0" />
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <assert TestID="RC_FB51_DE_005">
            <role></role>
            <TestName>entry id's (URNs)</TestName>
            <Report>verify the value is unique</Report>
            <diagnostics>for future use</diagnostics>
        </assert>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

This is the sample XML file being tested (also simplified for brevity):

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:cust="http://naesb.org/espi/customer"  
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://naesb.org/espi/customer retailcustomer.xsd" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <id>urn:uuid:A40AF787-89F3-4E52-AD26-214E2E0A9A76</id>
    <entry>
        <id>urn:uuid:131C82AB-0308-4C5B-A1B4-19F3E0A97014</id>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id>urn:uuid:131C82AB-0308-4C5B-A1B4-19F3E0A97014</id>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

I am limited to XSLT version 1.0, so the available XSLT test are limited.  I've also spent several days reviewing the current issues, but have not found a solution.

Comment: Your test will always be true, because an entry's id is always equal to itself. Try testing for count > 1. Even better, use the Muenchian method to detect duplicates.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks for the response.  I eventually determined that the answer is always 1 and changed the test to &gt; 1.